# Passing multiple parameters from window.location to action mvc

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am passing multiple parameters.but id is not coming in the webbrowser url.And an error is coming "passing null parameter".wat is the problem?

```
  window.location.href = "http://localhost:8088/Home/PostToFacebook/?msg=" + msg + "&itemid=" + itemid;
```

My action

```
public ActionResult PostToFacebook(string msg, int itemid) { return RedirectToAction("Item", new { id = itemid }); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the forward slash `/` before the `?msg` like

Should be

```
  window.location.href = "http://localhost:8088/Home/PostToFacebook?msg
```

instead of

```
  window.location.href = "http://localhost:8088/Home/PostToFacebook/?msg
```

Comment: this is my action      public ActionResult PostToFacebook(string msg, int itemid)
        {            return RedirectToAction("Item", new { id = itemid });

        }

Comment: Then there is must be problem around `msg` and `itemid` as it's fine at my localhost with dummy value with these variables.